# Are const static fields removed from the AST once they're evaluated? (optimisation)

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

In a for loop such as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i ++) {
    const static int test = i;
    ...
}
```

Since `test` can only be assigned to once (const) AND the it will not be stored in the stack (static) is it a compiler optimisation to completely remove the AST of `const static int test = i;` from the for loop block, in order to decrease the chance of cache misses during runtime, as less children are stored in the for loop's body? If not why?

My thought process behind this, is that once `test` is evaluated, further evaluation of `test` is ignored as it is `const static`. Therefore the AST of the `test` is no longer required.

Comment: Are you asking about optimizing the time it takes to compile the code or optimizing the time it takes to run the compiled code? Usually compiler optimizations are only concerned about the latter (in fact, if you want to optimize the former, it's best not to perform any optimizations at all because optimizations take time).

Comment: Yes I mean to optimise the time taken to run the code, not compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(For this answer I'll assume that the code is written in C++ or in any language whose relevant semantics are the same as C++'s.)

Compiler optimizations usually aren't performed at the AST level, but usually at the IR level (e.g. in clang most optimizations are performed at the LLVM level and that includes eliminating unnecessary variables).

But yes, it's legal (and in fact common) for an optimizing compiler to generate the same code as if you had directly used `0` instead of `test` everywhere you use it. The same is true if you remove the `const` keyword (as long as you don't actually reassign `test` anywhere).

If you also remove the `static` keyword, optimizing compilers will then almost certainly generate the same code as if you had used `i` everywhere you use `test` (assuming the value of `i` never changes between the declaration of `test` and any use of `test`).

Generally any optimization is legal if it does not change the observable behavior of a program (or if it only changes it in cases where the behavior would be undefined according to the rules of the language).

> in order to decrease the chance of cache misses during runtime, as less children are stored in the for loop's body

This seems to be a bit of a misunderstanding of how code is compiled and executed. The AST no longer exists when the compiled code is run, so how many children there were in the AST during compilation has no direct effect on the runtime of the program.

What matters is how often memory is accessed and whether the accessed locations are near each other. So when variables can't be optimized away, compilers will try to keep them in registers as much as possible. You can't miss the cache when you don't access memory at all.

Comment: In C this code is illegal, no? Could be C++, whose semantics for static variable initialisation are quite different.

Comment: @rici Indeed it is, good catch. I've changed it to "C++".

Comment: My bad, should have clarified - yes it is C++